# Quotient space and double cosets

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups

I'm reading Serre's *Trees* recently. I'm trying to prove that

> $\Gamma$ is a discrete torsion-free subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Q}_{p})$. If the quotient space $G/\Gamma$ is compact, then $S$ is finite, where $S$ is a set of double coset representatives for $\Gamma\backslash G/\mathrm{SL}_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})$.

This is a part of the proof (page 83) of Ch.2 Thm.5 in Serre's *Trees*.
At first, I was trying to prove that $\Gamma S$ is discrete in the quotient space.
But I failed. Someone know how to prove it? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I've improved your question's formatting; apologies if I changed your meaning. You can [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/11224fec-5760-48a5-8f3e-477b057755f1/view-source) how I edited your question.

[Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Thank you very much, Zev Chonoles.

Answer (score 1):

The subgroup $K=SL_2(\mathbb Z_p)$ is open in $G=SL_2(\mathbb Q_p)$. The quotient $\Gamma\backslash G$ has the quotient topology, of course. Then compact $\Gamma\backslash G$ is covered by finitely many translates of $K$.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the condition: $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Z}_{p})$ is open in $SL_{2}(\mathbb{Q}_{p})$. 
Thank for your help.